# Android TV ImageCardView title wrapping

Tags: java, android, android-tv

I am developing app for Android TV and using leanback library.

In [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/tvleanback/presenter/CardPresenter.java) from google they are using `public class CardPresenter extends Presenter` to display content. The problem is, that I want to display all text in titles, i.e. dont cut it.

[image]

I already tried:

1) To fix this problem by programmatically setting LayoutParams: `cardView.findViewById(R.id.title_text).setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`

2) I looked inside lb_image_card_view.xml file for [ImageCard](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/882ee91503f28d1fd60ba939c5b37db6b9d4ad29/sdk/extras/android/support/v17/leanback/res/layout/lb_image_card_view.xml). Funny moment, that TextView with id "title_text" already has `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` parameter, but looks like it doesn't work?? Is it a bug?

3) For a backup plan I can create my own class for ImageCardView, but this solution seems 2 hard.

Thx.

**Update.**

I used the answer below, but I have to modificative code for better performance:

```
cardView.setOnFocusChangeListener((view, isFocused) -> {
        if (isFocused) {
            ((TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.title_text)).setMaxLines(5);
        }
        else {
            ((TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.title_text)).setMaxLines(1);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to check this [tutorial](http://w9jds.github.io/walkthroughs/2014/08/26/replicating_android_tv_home_screen_imagecardview_expand) if it can help you. it helps you to show or display all the text in title.

Here is the code use for this tutorial

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
    final ImageCardView cardView = new ImageCardView(mContext);    

    cardView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, final boolean isFocused) {
            final View infoField = view.findViewById(R.id.info_field);
            final TextView contentField = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.content_text);
            final TextView titleField = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
            final Drawable mainImage = ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.main_image)).getDrawable();

            if (isFocused) {
                ((TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.title_text)).setMaxLines(3);
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams infoLayout = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                infoField.setLayoutParams(infoLayout);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams contentLayout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                contentLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.title_text);
                contentField.setLayoutParams(contentLayout);
            }
            else {
                ((TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.title_text)).setMaxLines(1);
            }
        }
    });

    cardView.setFocusable(true);
    cardView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    cardView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.fastlane_background));
    return new ViewHolder(cardView);
}
```

And here is the output of this code.

[image]

For more information, check this [thread](http://corochann.com/android-tv-application-hands-on-tutorial-3-105.html#ImageCardView) also.